# Is there a way to reference an externally declared `typedef std::function`?

Tags: cython

In a header file, I have the following declaration:

```cpp
typedef std::function<void()> Callback;

class MyClass
{
    Result DoStuff(Callback callback = nullptr);
    void DoStuff2();
}
```

Right now my Cython `pyx` file starts with:

```
cdef extern from "header.h" nogil:
    cdef cppclass MyClass:
        void DoStuff2()
```

Now, In Cython, I wish to use the function `MyClass.DoStuff`, and suppose that I can accept not passing anything as the callback, how can I import `Callback` even without attempting to use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you genuinely don't want to pass a callback and are happy using the default argument then simply don't tell Cython about it. Wrap it as a one-argument function:

```
cdef extern from "header.h" nogil:
    cdef cppclass MyClass:
        Result DoStuff()
        void DoStuff2()
```

(Note that you do need to tell Cython about `Result`.)

If you would like to pass a callback then you can `cimport` function from Cython's standard library wrappings

```
from libcpp.functional cimport function

cdef extern from "header.h" nogil:
    cdef cppclass MyClass:
        Result DoStuff(function[void() nogil] callback = NULL)
        ...
```

It probably isn't worth telling Cython about the typedef, but you can if you want with `ctypedef`. Note that I've added `nogil` to the signature, since I assume that the function will be called without the gil.